# Why user-defined metadata are not being added to object (aws s3api put-object?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have been trying to create a bucket and then an object with user-defined metadata inside it. To do so, I executed the following commands (or close variations of it):

`aws s3api create-bucket --bucket mybucket1`

```
aws s3api put-object --bucket mybucket1 \
                     --key mykey1 \
                     --body test_files/test-pattern-152459_960_720.png \
                     --metadata '{"x-amz-meta-author":"Test"}'
```

However, when I try to retrieve metadata from the object using the command

`aws s3api head-object --bucket mybucket1 --key mykey1`

the user-defined metadata is always empty:

```
{
    "ContentType": "binary/octet-stream",
    "LastModified": "Fri, 12 Nov 2021 12:01:17 GMT",
    "ContentLength": 18062,
    "Expires": "Fri, 12 Nov 2021 12:01:27 GMT",
    "ETag": "2021-11-12T12:01:17.457Z",
    "CacheControl": "no-cache",
    "Metadata": {}
}
```

The commands do not give any error, but it like some of the options are completely ignored. I also tried to create/update the object with the command:

`awks s3api head-object --cli-input-json '{...}'`

I am omitting the json to avoid cluttering, but I scrupulously followed the template generated via the '--generate-cli-skeleton' option. The result is the same as above: I wasn’t able to add anything to Metadata, nor to change the ContentType field. I also tried modifying the alc to public-read-write, but nothing changed.

Am I overlooking something? I can’t see what I’m doing wrong.

'put-object' doc page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-object.html

Comment: This works fine for me and head-object yields the metadata. Note that you should probably use `author` rather than `x-amz-meta-author` otherwise the metadata key will actually become `x-amz-meta-x-amz-meta-author` (with doubled prefix),  which you can see in the S3 console for the object. Make sure you have an up to date awscli. Also, include content-type.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I tried again but again without any success. I am using a dockerized version of Apache Ozone (apache/ozone:1.1.0) and executing the commands from within the S3 container: could this be an issue? The aws version is aws-cli/1.14.28. In which environment are you using aws?

Answer (score 0):

Your awscli version is [1.14.28](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/releases/tag/1.14.28), dated January 2018. That's almost 4 years old. I tested with an up to date v2 awscli and this worked correctly.

I think you should [install](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html) the latest awscli and re-test.

Whether or not Apache Ozone's S3 API implementation actually supports custom metadata is not clear. Their S3 API docs don't give any details on how compatible their PUT/HEAD emulation is.

Comment: Just updated it to aws-cli/2.3.6, but nothing changed...

Comment: Looks like Apache Ozone includes an object store with an S3 compatible API. It supports PUT and HEAD. among other things, but the documentation doesn't go into any details about custom metadata. You might want to investigate how compatible Ozone's S3 API actually is.